# i get "Error running 'main.dart': Entrypoint isn't within a Flutter pub root" every time i try to run my app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

i'm working on app using flutter and android studio this is the error I get every time i try to run my app
i tired running other projects and they ran completely fine

[image]

Comment: try File -> Project Structure -> Module
And then add the root folder of the project, then it will detect that its a flutter app again, and then build and work again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a failed rebuild.

1. Click on `File` at the top left corner on the menu bar.
2. Click `Project Structure`
3. Click on `Module` at the left end, then click on `sources`.
4. You will then see your project directory below the language level. Ensure that this path is correct and points to the root folder of your project. That is the project folder. If not update it and click `Ok` at the bottom of the dialog.
5. On the menu bar click on `Build` then `rebuild project`.

Comment: im not sure i understand the 3rd step

Comment: thank you for updating the answer, still gives me the same error, I checked the sources and everything was correct

Comment: Have you tried syncing project with gradle files

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue recently and I don't know how or why but I somehow my main.dart file was no longer listed as a dart file - I Resolved this by right clicking the main.dart file in Android Studio. Clicked the menu option that populates 'Mark as Dart' afterwards no issues - it compiled and a lot less hair for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and tried everything and nothing was working.

Then i realised that the `pubspec.yaml` was not there. So i restored it with git and poof everything was working again.

It was deleted (but not committed) and restored I it with `git checkout HEAD pubspec.yaml` in my case